# DataTables : DeferLoading is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatables

I have a mysql table with about 30000 rows. I have to put all rows in a DataTable and load each segment each time a table page is loaded (when you click on pagination). I saw that I can use the deferLoading parameter in my JS, but when I use it my pages are not loading. As you can see, I have to load images, so I absolutely have to do a light loading of the content...

Here is my HTML :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover datatable products-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><?=_("Product")?></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><?=_("Product")?></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Here is my JS :

```
var table = $('.products-datatable').dataTable( {
    "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "deferLoading": 30000,
    "ajax": {
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/ajax/products.php?action=list',
        type: "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "image",
          "orderable": false,
          "width": "80px" },
        { "data": "product" },
        { "data": "action",
          "orderable": false,
          "width": "20px",
          "sClass": "class", 
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is my AJAX :

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT product_id, name FROM products');

if ( $req->execute() ) {

    if ($req->rowCount()) {

        $result['draw'] = 1;
        $result['recordsTotal'] = $req->rowCount();
        $result['recordsFiltered'] = 10;
        $result['data'] = array();
        $result['DT_RowId'][] = array();

        while( $row = $req->fetch() ) {

            if ($row['name']) { $name = $row['name']; } else { $name = "N/A"; }

            $result['data'][] = array(  "DT_RowId"      =>  $row['product_id'],
                                        "DT_RowClass"   =>  'myclass',
                                        "image"         =>  '<a href="' . HOSTNAME._("product").'/'.$row['product_id'] . '"><img src="' . HOSTNAME.'assets/img/products/' . $row['product_id'] . '.jpg" class="product_thumb"></a>',
                                        "product"       =>  '<a href="' . HOSTNAME._("product").'/'.$row['product_id'] . '">' . $name . '</a>',
                                        "action"        =>  "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button-delete\" id=\"" . $row['product_id'] . "\"><i class=\"fa fa-close fa-2x text-danger\"></i></a>"
                                        );

        }

    }

}

$req->closeCursor();
```

I'm sure there is something I missed... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need to use `deferLoading` to benefit from server-side processing.

Your current script just returns all records and doesn't do sorting or filtering. You need to use `ssp.class.php` (available in DataTables distribution package) or [emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp) class to correctly handle AJAX requests on the server.

DataTables library will send `start` and `length` parameters in AJAX request indicating which portion of the data is needed and your server-side processing class will correctly handle it for you.

Please see an example of [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) for more information.